# jQuery not correctly recognizing when CSS animation end event triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, events

What I have been attempting to implement is a function that will be called to trigger an error animation using the `.one();` function in jQuery. When I validate a form and it fails, I call the triggerError function in my code, sending it the element that needs to have the animation applied to it. The `.error` animation class is correctly applied, but the `.one();` function does not recognize that the animation has completed in order to remove the `.error` class.

Here is the Javascript that listens for the click and attempts to apply and remove the animation class:

```
$('#search').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        triggerError($(this).parent());
        return;
    }
});

function triggerError(input) {
    input.addClass('error');

    input.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
        input.removeClass('error');
    });
}
```

I've also created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/wXadYd) to illustrate this error on an input.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `animation`, not `transition` - so you should listen to `animationend` event:

```js
$('#search').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    triggerError($(this).parent());
    return;
  }
});

function triggerError(input) {
  console.log('start');
  input.addClass('error');

  input.one('webkitAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
    input.removeClass('error');
    console.log('stop');
  });
}
```

```css
.inline-form {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
}

.inline-form input {
  flex-grow: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

.inline-form .input-button {
  height: 2.3125rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes error {
  from {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  to {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
}

.error {
  animation-name: error;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-form">
  <label for="search-input" class="hidden"></label><input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button id="search" class="input-button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that, I guess I just needed a second set of eyes. Thank you so much!